# Update the org-agenda-daily-view automatically on background

Tags: org-mode

The org-agenda-daily-view is fancily helpful as a review,
Additionally, I want to append a real-time now line as time elapsed.

[image]

This could be achieved by a work around solution, repeatedly kill and open the daily agenda buffer .

Is it possible to make it update automatically say every five minutes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use timers for this.  `run-with-timer` allows you to run a command every `N` seconds.  `run-with-idle-timer` is similar but the command runs only after Emacs has been idle for a number of seconds.  An argument to both functions will cause the timer to repeat instead of just firing once. I prefer idle timers so they don't interrupt my typing.

To regenerate the default agenda view (with command "a") every 5 minutes (300 seconds):

```
(run-with-idle-timer 300 t (lambda () (org-agenda nil "a")) )
```

Comment: thank you. org-agenda nil means invoke org-agenda but not call a?

Comment: If you don't give a second argument it will open the agenda menu to prompt you.

Comment: Excellent!. Is there a way to do this without focusing the agenda buffer, though?

Comment: @loki Try wrapping the `org-agenda` call with `save-window-excursion`

Comment: will this only work if org-agenda is activated right?

Answer (score 2):

erikstokes's [answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/47266/30158) will only run the command one time with 300s delay every time the user becomes idle:

> Emacs becomes idle when it starts waiting for user input, and it remains idle until the user provides some input. If a timer is set for five seconds of idleness, it runs approximately five seconds after Emacs first becomes idle. **Even if repeat is non-nil, this timer will not run again as long as Emacs remains idle, because the duration of idleness will continue to increase and will not go down to five seconds again.** ([source](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Idle-Timers.html))

To make it automatically update every five minutes (even during idle), we can do something like this (reference: the code in https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Idle-Timers.html):

```
(defvar refresh-agenda-time-seconds 300)

(defvar refresh-agenda-timer nil
  "Timer for `refresh-agenda-timer-function' to reschedule itself, or nil.")

(defun refresh-agenda-timer-function ()
  ;; If the user types a command while refresh-agenda-timer
  ;; is active, the next time this function is called from
  ;; its main idle timer, deactivate refresh-agenda-timer.
  (when refresh-agenda-timer
    (cancel-timer refresh-agenda-timer))

  (org-agenda nil "a")

  (setq refresh-agenda-timer
    (run-with-idle-timer
      ;; Compute an idle time break-length
      ;; more than the current value.
      (time-add (current-idle-time) refresh-agenda-time-seconds)
      nil
      'refresh-agenda-timer-function)))

(run-with-idle-timer refresh-agenda-time-seconds t 'refresh-agenda-timer-function)
```